# Symfony - How to format an entity field in a form (to display more fields than just title)?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a `form` where user can submit a new **Mandate**. Every **Mandate** can have multiple **Profiles** linked to it.

Here is how the `form` looks like at this moment:

[image]

The **Profiles** field is added to the form like that (from `MandateController`):

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($mandate)
->add('content')
->add('name')
->add('company_name')
->add('budget')
->add('phone')
->add('email')
->add('description')
->add('profiles', EntityType::class, array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'class' => 'KrownDashboardBundle:Profile',
    'choice_label' => 'title',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->orderBy('p.title', 'ASC');
    },
))
->getForm();
```

And the view is handled this way:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <div>
        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="" class="control-label">{{ form_label(form.content) }}</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.content, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.content) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Prénom et nom</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Nom de lentreprise</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.company_name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.company_name) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Budget</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.budget, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.budget) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Numéro de téléphone</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.phone, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.phone) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="" class="control-label">E-mail</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Description</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.description, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.description) }}
        </div>

        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Profiles</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.profiles) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.profiles) }}
        </div>

    </div>
<button id="login-form-submit" class="button button-3d button-black nomargin" value="Log in" name="login-form-submit">Ok</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I want to modify the **Profiles** listing, so they look like this (all these fields are saved into the **Profile** entity):

[image]

Instead:

[image]

How can I achieve that? What's the best way to do it?

Comment: You are going to have to create a custom FormType, create a service for it and then create a new Twig form fragment for it. In the new FormType you'll need to overwrite' `finishView`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Can you give me more information about your solution? The custom FormType is for Mandate entity or Profile entity?

Comment: No it's a custom `FormType` like `ExtendedEntityType::class` instead of `EntityType::class` then you pass all the data you need (via the `option_attributes`) to the overridden `radio_widget` twig fragment. Then use css styles.
There was an issue on github where someone posted some code to send extra data to expanded choice (entity) types. I'd search the symfony/symfony issues. If you can find it and if I get time, I can post an answer. Just crazy busy right now.